# How Can I make the source field as dropdown

Tags: extension

I remember there used to be an extension that would make the source field as a dropdown instead of an editable field, cant seem to remember how it's called! Anyone?

EDIT: I think It’s the contribution source field. When adding a contribution this extension would make the source field a dropdown instead of a text. The dropdown would be the list picked up from existing data from contribution source field.

Comment: You mean filter the dropdown? or do you mean the source contact of an activity should be allowed to update on edit activity form?

Comment: Do you mean the source field for the contact  (appearing at the top left of the summary tab). There are other fields called source (eg in contributions and memberships) so I think you need to provide a bit more information.

Comment: Thanks @PradeepNayak updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.textselect

Depending what you're trying to achieve, using campaigns is an alternative (which is already a dropdown) that may make sense.

See https://civicrm.org/blog/stoob/new-ways-track-referral-source for putting it all together.

Comment: Thanks. Textselect is the one I was looking for but didn’t remember what it was called.